# drupal 7 block restriction based on user term reference

Tags: drupal, drupal-taxonomy, drupal-blocks

Users are set up on my D7 site with various term references as profile fields.

I need to be able to show hide certain blocks based on these term references, is this possible?

I cant see a way to link a block with a term reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to enable php filter and set 
Show block on specific pages ->  Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE (experts only) 
in the block settings.

then you can access the user profile field terms of the logged in user like this

```
 global $user;
 $user = user_load($user->uid); 

 $term1 = $user->field_term1[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']; //the value should be the tid of the term
 $term2 = $user->field_term2[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'];
```

then you can return true accordingly to control the visibility of the block.

for example

```
       return $term1 == 15 //this is the tid of the term
```

The above code will show the block only to users with custom field term with tid = 15

Hope I am not confusing you.